# using cin.get() function

Tags: c++, function, get

```
char arr[100];
cin.get(arr,100);
```

1. Is this safe? Will the null-character be appended at the end even if I type more than 100 chars? or should I use `cin.get(arr,99)`?
2. When I type ENTER, is the end-of-line character part of the array or not?

Comment: Are you sure anything like that is a good idea when you want to _type_ in something?

Comment: @leftaroundabout what do u mean. I guess My questions are clear.

Comment: Yes, it's just very awkward and error-prone if you're required to type in an exact number of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to both of your questions can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get), but to reiterate:

1. The `get` method reads at most `n - 1` characters. This means that the method expects the size of the *buffer* and not the number of characters to read. This method automatically appends a null character to the end.
2. The newline character is *not* extracted or stored in the array.

You may also want to consider using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which you can use in conjunction with `std::string`.

Comment: so cin.get(arr,100) is the correct one. and this will read 99 characters and leave 1 character for the null character to be appended at the end. is this correct? thanks.

Comment: @AlexDan: That's correct. You pass in 100 because 100 is the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

> 1)is this safe. I mean will the null-character be appended
>   at the end. even if I typed more than 100 chars. or it must be cin.get(arr,99).

Taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

The signature of `get` you are using looks like this:

`basic_istream& get( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );`

It will read at most `count - 1` characters from the stream (in your case 99) or up until the delimiting character, which is by default `\n`. So if you type more than 100 characters, a call to `get` will read 99 of those characters and then append the null terminator `\0` at the end.

> 2)also when I type ENTER, a newline get passed. so does this character is really a part of the array or not.

No, `get` read up until the delimiting character, so if you press ENTER, `\n` will be left in the stream as the next character to be read.

Advice:
Please use the site I linked to in order to understand how these functions work, and prefer `std::string` and `std::getline` if you are coding in C++.